# How to add access to the camera to one app which doesn't appears in the system preferences ->privacy menu?

Tags: macbook-pro, applications, permission, camera

Hi I have an app which take screenshoots from my macbook, but I didn't give access to the camera when I installed the app, that's why I am not able to use this app now, which has very nice tools to comment and edit the screenshoots. My question is, how can I give permissions to this app if it doesn't appears in the menu system preferences -> privacity -> camera, how can I add this app to this section or give the camera permissions? Thanks!

[image]

The app is lightshot I was able to use it in another mac, where I gave the permissions when I installed it, the another problem here is that when I installed it again it didn't ask me to give permissions maybe for some kind of history.

For more clarity, what I would like to do is to be able to show the lighshot app in the privacy -> camera section, just as in the next picture.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Cant you just drag the .app itself into the appropriate preferences pane window to add it? Or did I hallucinate that? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps only appear in privacy settings when they attempt to use the category.

The Camera privacy settings refers to photographs and videos from the built-in camera, which is not something Lightshot uses.

The list on the left of Privacy settings also contains Screen Recording lower down, which is what is required for apps to be able to take screenshots.

Comment: As I mentioned before in another mac it appears in the privacy -> camera section and I am not able to use it in this mac, because I didn't give camera permissions when I installed it, I hope this point will be clear.